# Loop through data on DGV then save each

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, datagridview

I get this error:
[image]
When I try to execute this code:

```
Public con = New OleDbConnection 'on a module
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "pigletsNew.accdb")
    con.Open()

Dim query As String = "UPDATE Piglets SET Mortality=@mortality, CurrentLocation=@me" & _
        " WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMortality.Rows
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@mortality", dgvMortality.Columns("mortality"))
                .AddWithValue("@me", "Mortality")
                .AddWithValue("@week", dgvMortality.Columns("week"))
                .AddWithValue("@so", dgvMortality.Columns("so"))
                .AddWithValue("@pig", dgvMortality.Columns("pig"))
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
```

I hard coded columns of dgv which are week, so, pig, mortality. I tried to add data on the dgv,
for example : `01 01 0001 12/12/12`, respectively, then I get the error above.
My purpose is to "*Temporary save*" data files on the dgv first before actually saving it to the database. 
What am I missing?

Comment: You might need to clear the parameters before adding again ... `.Clear()` 
`.AddWithValue(...)`

Comment: I added `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` after executenonquery. Also, I only inserted one data, still the same error.

Comment: how did you declare `con` and what is your `ConnectionString`?

Comment: another problem is this ... `dgvMortality.Columns("mortality")` returns `DataGridViewColumn` ... so, you might want to use this ... `row.Cells("mortality").Value`

Comment: Add that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following codes, `dgvMortality.Columns("...")` will return `DataGridViewColumn`

```
.AddWithValue("@mortality", dgvMortality.Columns("mortality"))
.AddWithValue("@me", "Mortality")
.AddWithValue("@week", dgvMortality.Columns("week"))
.AddWithValue("@so", dgvMortality.Columns("so"))
.AddWithValue("@pig", dgvMortality.Columns("pig"))
```

Adding `DataGridViewColumn` as a `OledbCommand Parameter` will cause the error.

Should use

```
.AddWithValue("@mortality", row.Cells("mortality").Value)
.AddWithValue("@me", "Mortality")
.AddWithValue("@week", row.Cells("week").Value)
.AddWithValue("@so", row.Cells("so").Value)
.AddWithValue("@pig", row.Cells("pig").Value)
```